# Facebook Mobile Payments Currency

Tags: facebook

The graph api returns a set of price points that include payer_amount and payout_base_amount in the user's currency.

How can we obtain these amounts in US dollars, so we compare it to the product:price:amount in the product url (we only have USD set in the product url).

Thanks!

Comment: What currency do you currently get them in?

Comment: It depends on the user's country. This is an example of what facebook returns:
<code>
      {
        "id": "x1b2dedt...",           // encoded pricepoint id
        "payer_amount": "2.00",        // user pays 2.00 EUR
        "payout_base_amount": "1.40",  // developer gets EUR 1.40 * 70% rev share
        "currency": "EUR",
        "country": "DE"
      }
</code>